# What happens to a VectorView object when its underlying Vector get garbage collected?

Tags: vector, windows-runtime, c++-cx

Let's say I have a function which internally creates a new `Platform::Collections::Vector^` and adds a few items to it. If the function returns a `Platform::Collections::VectorView^` which was fetched by calling the `GetView()` function on the Vector, could:

1. The Vector be garbage collected (that is, would it's ref-count go down to 0) when the function returns? Or would calling GetView() increase the ref-count by 1?
2. If so, what happens to the VectorView that got returned? Does it hold a copy of all the items from the Vector that was used to create the VectorView?

In other words, is the function below safe?

```
Platform::Collections::VectorView^ MyClass::MyFunction()
{
    Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>^ vec = 
        ref new Platform::Collections::Vector<Platform::String^>();
    vec->Append(L"Hello");
    vec->Append(L"World");
    return vec->GetView();
}
```

Comment: The vector view does whatever it needs to ensure that it can implement its requirements. This might entail taking a reference to the vector. Or it might mean making a copy of the items. That's an implementation detail. The code is safe. It is the vector view's responsibility to ensure that it can produce items when requested.